# Is there any way to login via Selenium VBA with HTML Form element?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my VBA Code. And image attached is the Source Code

[image]

```
bot.FindElementById("txtBoxUsername").SendKeys "Username"
bot.FindElementById("txtBoxPassword").SendKeys "Password"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.FindElementById("txtBoxPassword").Submit
```

Once you enter password, call submit on any form element . IT will submit the form